# PHP no devuelve JSON adecuadamente

Tags: php

Tengo mi controlador:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once "./App/Models/ArticulosModel.php";

    class ArticulosController{
        private $jsonResponse = array("status" => 500, "data" => null, "message" => null);
        private $model;
        private $jwt;
        private $token;
        
        public function __construct(){
            $this->model = new ArticulosModel;
            $this->jwt = new JsonWebToken;
        }
        public function listarTodos($req, $res){
                $array=$this->model->listarTodos();

                if ($array){
              
                    $this->jsonResponse['status']=200;
                    $this->jsonResponse['message']="Datos obtenidos satisfactoriamente";
                    $this->jsonResponse['data']=$array;
           
        }

        $res->status($this->jsonResponse['status'])->send($this->jsonResponse);
         
}
    }
?>
```

como veran llama al modelo que le devuelve un array de articulos dentro de data, es decir dentro del array jsonResponse.

El caso es que si pongo `var_dump($this->jsonResponse);`antes del send en Postman obtengo el array perfectamente. Pero asi como esta el codigo no devuelve nada..es una tabla de productos de 28 mil registros.

Por otro lado ya probe modificar en el php.ini la variable memory_limit y nada no funciona.

el problema podria estar en el modelo?

```
<?php

class ArticulosModel{
      public $conn;

      public function __construct(){
          $database = new Database;
          $this->conn = $database->getConnection();
      }
      public function listarTodos(){
   
              $sqlarticulos="SELECT * FROM productos LEFT JOIN marca ON productos.id_marca=marca.Id_marca LEFT JOIN categoria ON productos.id_categoria=categoria.Id_categoria LEFT JOIN subcategoria ON subcategoria.id_subcategoria=productos.id_subcategoria;";
              $sql=$this->conn->prepare($sqlarticulos);
      
       
              $sql->execute();
              $array=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

              return $array;     
            }
}
?>
```

Para mi esta aqui: `$array=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Bueno paso a mostrar mi array:

```
array(20) {
[0]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "1"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "300.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(7) "XTC-500"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(45) "ADITIVO PARA ACEITE XTC SINTETICO 12 X 500 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[1]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "2"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "220.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(9) "NOSMP-400"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(40) "ADITIVO PARA ACEITE NO SMOKE 24 x 400 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[2]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "3"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "240.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(10) "MCFLEX-400"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(23) "M�XIMA FLEX 18 X 400 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[3]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "4"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "480.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(10) "MCFLEX-001"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(20) "M�XIMA FLEX 12 X 1 L"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[4]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "5"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "220.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "6"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(7) "NCD-250"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(30) "CAJA Y DIFERENCIAL 12 x 250 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(9) "ACEITE 2T"
}
[5]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "6"
["precio"]=>
string(5) "55.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "6"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(6) "2T-100"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(27) "ACEITE 2T MOTOS 48 x 100 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(9) "ACEITE 2T"
}
[6]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "7"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "100.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "6"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(6) "2T-200"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(27) "ACEITE 2T MOTOS 24 x 200 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(9) "ACEITE 2T"
}
[7]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "8"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "325.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "6"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(6) "2T-001"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(24) "ACEITE 2T MOTOS 12 x 1 L"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(9) "ACEITE 2T"
}
[8]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(1) "9"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "370.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "6"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(10) "2TNAUT-001"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(26) "ACEITE 2T NAUTICA 12 x 1 L"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(9) "ACEITE 2T"
}
[9]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "10"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "190.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(9) "FTASK-350"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(56) "FLUIDO TRANSMISIONES HIDRAULICAS C/STOP LEAK 24 x 350 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[10]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "11"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "420.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(9) "FTASK-001"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(53) "FLUIDO TRANSMISIONES HIDRAULICAS C/STOP LEAK 12 x 1 L"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[11]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "12"
["precio"]=>
string(7) "1320.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(10) "FTASK-4004"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(52) "FLUIDO TRANSMISIONES HIDRAULICAS C/STOP LEAK 4 x 4 L"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[12]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "13"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "215.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(9) "PROTE-160"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(55) "RUST PROTEK LUBRICANTE MULTIUSO C/EXHIBIDORA 12 x 160 g"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[13]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "14"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "240.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(9) "PROTE-220"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(55) "RUST PROTEK LUBRICANTE MULTIUSO C/EXHIBIDORA 12 x 220 g"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[14]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "15"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "110.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(8) "2TPJ-200"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(39) "ACEITE 2T PARQUE Y JARDINES 24 x 200 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[15]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "16"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "230.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "5"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(7) "ELC-240"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(39) "ESPUMA LUBRICANTE P/CADENAS 12 x 240 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(15) "GAS OIL - NAFTA"
}
[16]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "17"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "145.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(8) "INYE-110"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(35) "LIMPIA INYECTORES NAFTA 24 x 110 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(8) "LIMPIEZA"
}
[17]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "18"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "190.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(8) "INYE-250"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(35) "LIMPIA INYECTORES NAFTA 24 X 250 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(8) "LIMPIEZA"
}
[18]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "19"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "275.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(8) "INYE-500"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(35) "LIMPIA INYECTORES NAFTA 12 x 500 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(8) "LIMPIEZA"
}
[19]=>
array(19) {
["Id_producto"]=>
string(2) "20"
["precio"]=>
string(6) "125.00"
["stock"]=>
string(1) "0"
["id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["id_subcategoria"]=>
string(1) "3"
["id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["cod_alfanumerico"]=>
string(12) "INYEMOTO-110"
["cod_barra"]=>
string(1) "0"
["aliiva"]=>
string(5) "21.00"
["unidad"]=>
string(0) ""
["contenido"]=>
NULL
["costo"]=>
NULL
["NombreProducto"]=>
string(47) "LIMPIA INYECTORES Y CARBURADOR MOTO 24 x 110 ml"
["Id_marca"]=>
string(1) "1"
["logo"]=>
string(1) "0"
["nombre_marca"]=>
string(7) "BARDAHL"
["Id_categoria"]=>
string(1) "2"
["nombre_categoria"]=>
string(8) "ADITIVOS"
["nombre_subcategoria"]=>
string(8) "LIMPIEZA"
}
}
```

Como veran tiene un array por registro identificado por un numero.
Esto me devuelve hacer **var_dump($array);** Tendria que pasarlo a un JSON para devolverlo en "data".

Comment: El título de la pregunta es sobre Angular y el contenido es sobre PHP ¿En qué parte está el problema entonces?

Comment: Acabo de editar el titulo de la pregunta, y el contenido

Comment: ¿Dijiste 28,000 registros? Deberías pensar seriamente en paginar los datos, a no ser que haya algo que justifique **realmente** tener que mostrar 28,000 registros en una página. De entrada, para descartar que no sea un problema **únicamente de memoria**, pon un `LIMIT 10`  a la instrucción SQL. Si los datos se muestran ya sabrás que debes implementar paginación. Si siguen sin mostrarse, será un indicativo de que hay otros problemas, lo cual no significa que te librarás de paginar esos resultados. Es inviable desde todo punto de vista mostrar miles de registros de golpe.

Comment: Si, ya habia probado usar "limit 10"ynodevuelve nada. Para mi puede estar en el array asociativo de fetchAll() se me hace, porque es un array dentro de otro.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($array);` para depurar. La documentación advierte sobre posibles problemas de memoria al usar `fetchAll` con muchos resultados. Deberías usar  `fetch` e ir paginando tus datos, como te comenté más arriba.

Comment: Acabo de probar con 20 registros y no devuelve nada. Si pongo fetch solo devuelveel primer registro pero con fetchAll no devuelve nada

Comment: Con `fetchAll()` y un `LIMIT 10` en la consulta prueba algo así: `return $array[0];` y haz debug de lo que recibes en el cliente.

Comment: De hecho habia pensado que estoy devolviendo un array asociativo y esto no se codifica dentro del json de respuesta dado que son mucho array dentro de uno. Con return $array[0]; funciona solo que obviamente devuelve solo elprimer registro de la tabla entonces de que manera podria iterar sobre el array asociativo y cargar en "data" los valores.

Comment: Interesaría ver cómo está estructurado el array para poder decirte la forma en que debe ser leído.

Comment: Que dice en tu error.log ?

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta y coloque el JSON, no obtengo errores en error.log.

Comment: Todo está OK. Ahora simplemente quita los `var_dump` y cualquier otra salida por pantalla que hayas puesto y lee el jsonResponse allí donde lo recibas (supongo que lo recibes en el cliente, por tanto, debes leer el array usando código Javascript).